# SharePoint 2013 Style Library file not accessible with read permission

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, permissions, style-library, read, contribute

I have a **Content Editor** webpart in a page which refers some images in **Style Library**. When users who have read permission to **Style Library** are not able to view those images in page. When I give Contribute permission to that group, user is able to view those images in page. I don't want to give Contribute permission to the user.

Please suggest what I can do to view those images in page.

Comment: Store the images in a site assets/image library. Style library uses a custom permission group that should not be tinkered with.

Comment: you need to checkout/checkin and publish the images. If the images are not published, then it wont be visible